# Increase server's logical drive support

Tags: hardware, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have an HPE ProLiant DL360p Gen8 Server, with one P420i controller.
As I read in its [specification](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c03243992#N102C4), the controller's limit is 2 logical drives. What part(s) should I buy in order to increase it to 8 drives?

Comment: It says 64 logical drives, but 2 logical volumes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the controller already supports eight logical drives.

Comment: @GregAskew No it doesn't! It supports 8 logical drives with *cache*. Without cache it support only 2. And I'm not sure if I have a cache module.

Comment: @one_hell_of_a_guy: It's extremely unusual for a business to not have a cache module for a storage controller. It costs $15? And performance is poor without it. Also it seems like the only person who could be sure isn't sure.

Comment: I'm not familiar with servers at all, that's why I'm asking here. I said that according to HPE SSA behavior I DON'T have a cache module, even though everyone says it's very unlikely. I suspect that it's disabled but I don't know how to activate it.

Comment: @one_hell_of_a_guy: This may be a better fit in a forum such as Reddit Homelab.  https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The P420i *with zero cache* is limited to two logical volumes. When a cache module is present (likely) the logical volume limit is 64: https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/c04111534

So, make sure you've got a cache module fitted (FBWC). iLO or Smart Storage Administrator (SSA) should display that information. I'd definitely *not* recommend using such a controller without cache - especially the write performance is *very* poor.

Comment: I think the server doesn't have a cache module, or I don't know how to activate it. Because HPE SSA lets me create only 2 logical drives no matter what I do, I think the server doesn't have an enabled cache module. _"I'd definitely not recommend using such a controller without cache."_, what other choices do I have?

Comment: Short of getting an FBWC module (don't think any activation is required but would check the manual and verify inside the server) you're stuck with that limitation (or replacing the P420i altogether).

Comment: Also wanted to point out that zero-cache performance sucks and I wouldn't want to use it that way.

Comment: Eventually I ordered https://www.ebay.com/itm/192647030097?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=Yn4wwighT_-&sssrc=2349624&ssuid=&widget_ver=artemis&media=COPY. I hope it's compatible with my controller (P420i), it only states compatibility with P420. Do you know if it's compatible?

Comment: The Quickspecs linked above lists 631681-B21 for the 2GB module, so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues:

- Logical Drives are different than Physical Drives
- A Logical Drive is comprised of one or more Physical Drives
- The specification you link to says, *"Zero Memory, Up to 2 logical volumes (8SFF or 4LFF physical drives)"* - this only applies to a P420i controller that has zero cache memory. Your server likely has a cache module, so this shouldn't be a concern.

Does that make sense?

Comment: How do I check if my server has a cache module? And why HPE SSA limits me to create only 2 smart arrays, instead of letting me create an array to each drive (one physical drive is one logical drive).

Comment: @one_hell_of_a_guy iLO should display that. "one physical drive is one logical drive" kinda contradicts the use of a RAID controller. Are you looking for an HBA?

Comment: I'm not really sure and not familiar with the term "HBA". I described what I need, do you think that's HBA?

Comment: @one_hell_of_a_guy A *host bus adapter* is used to attach SATA, SAS, FC, ... storage devices to a computer, explicitly *without* RAID features. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_adapter

Comment: Why are you trying to create a single logical drive per logical disk?